# How to run and understand CUDA Visual Profiler?

Tags: cuda, analyzer

I had setup CUDA 5.0 and my project of CUDA work good,  but I don't know how to analyze my CUDA project with Visual Profiler ? How to run it ?

Have I need to install some more ? And how to do it ?

My computer use Window 7 64 bit, CUDA 5.0 64 bit, VS 2012

Answer (score 1):

The visual profiler is launched by typing:

```
nvvp
```

at a windows command prompt.

You may wish to read [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#visual-profiler)